# Apache: Redirect a specific incoming route to another internal url

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

When a user access to this URL of my website `http://mywebiste.com`, he is redirected to my documentRoot folder located in `/var/www/polo/current/public`.

I would like to add another rule to redirect all calls to `http://mywebsite.com/telka` to `http://10.10.21.21/doc/test`.

How can i do that ?

Here is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/polo/current/public

  <Directory /var/www/polo/current/public/>
      Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Alias` directive in the official documentation. That documentation is of excellent quality, as typical for OpenSource projects. And it comes with good examples. Do not forget to add a `<Directory ...>` section to your configuration that matches the `Alias` directive. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html